# Sequential Increment in Alphanumeric Invoice Number using MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have a table named as sales. In this table i have a column Invoice_Number. What i want to achieve is to get invoice number in alphanumeric sequential order i.e. one Static Letter and then a number that changes just like A1,A2,A3... and so on. i don't want to change A to B as i saw in rest of the examples.

I can get the numeric increment by this query:

```
Select IsNull(MAX([Invoice_Number] + 1), 1) from sales
```

But it cannot add an alphabet prior to it.

Thanks.

Comment: You do not want to do this to yourself. You are creating a race condition. Why do you have to have an 'A' at the front of your invoice number? Does it really matter if it is stored in the database with an A? Couldn't you just stick that letter on for invoices and other communication? Or use a computed column to append the A to the front.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a cast like so to return a varchar, let me know if this helps :).

```
SELECT 'A' + CAST(ISNULL(MAX([Invoice_Number] + 1), 1) AS nvarchar) FROM sales
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your existing [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) as a seed.  Combine this with a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) to return the `InvoiceNumber`.

```
-- Combine a seed with a computed column.
CREATE TABLE #Example
(
    Seed            INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    InvoiceNumber   AS 'A' + CAST(Seed AS VARCHAR(5)),
    Customer        VARCHAR(25)
);

-- Add some sample records.
INSERT INTO #Example
(
    Customer
)
VALUES

    ('A PLC'),
    ('B PLC'),
    ('C LTD')
;

-- Returns InvoiceNumbers A1, A2 & A3.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Example
;
```

Comment: Or you can create a separate sequence if you want to avoid holes in your invoice numbering/ e.g. when a draft record was deleted.

CREATE SEQUENCE InvoiceCounter
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
select 'A'+cast(next value for InvoiceCounter as nvarchar )